# How can I extract the filename from a path?

Tags: javascript, regex

The path from which I want to extract the filename takes the form:

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\Folder5\x.png
```

This should give x (I do not need the extension). The file is always a PNG file. x can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 digits, but can never contain any other character (only a number).

I tried a 'manual' method, which is working well.

```
function getId(x) {
  x = x.slice(0,-4);
  var str = "";
  var flag = 0;
  for(var i = x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(!isNaN(x[i])) {
      str = x[i] + str;
      flag = 1;
    } else if(flag == 1) {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(str);
}
```

Is there any simpler approach without using a library?

Comment: `x.replace(/^.*[\\\/]([^\\\/]+)\.[^\\\/.]+$/, "$1")` - extracting the maximal trailing portion of the path not containing a path separator up to the last `.`.

Comment: Do you mean you want the result to be `1` or did you mean `x` (1 is in the root folder, x is the filename without extension)

Comment: If it's always this format just split on `/`, then pop the last item in the array, then split that on `.` you don't need regex

Comment: @PatrickMoore sorry, I meant it should give x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match one or more times a digit in a capturing group. Then match a dot and not a backslash one or more times using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and assert the end of the string.

[`(\d+)\.[^\\]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/2k5ogM/1)

```js
const regex = /(\d+)\.[^\\]+$/;
const str = "C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4\\Folder5\\1.png";
console.log(str.match(regex)[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` and `pop()` to get the file name without extension:

```js
var file = 'C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4\\Folder5\\x.png';
var fileName = file.split(/\\/).pop();
fileName = fileName.split('.')[0];
console.log(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but so simple:

```
const str = 'C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Folder4\\Folder5\\t.png';
const getId = path => path.split('\\').pop().split('.')[0];
console.log(getId(str));
```